# Making Money On YouTube Video API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I've heard this is possible, but I'm having trouble finding the information on exactly how to set it up. I have a website where users can view information about specific objects, and on most pages we have youtube videos embedded (WE DID NOT CREATE THE VIDEOS, we're just displaying them to users through the YouTube API).

Apparently there is a way to make money off each user playback, any ideas how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only generate revenue from a video if you are the creator and owner of it (through [AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2530958?hl=en-GB)). There is no way to generate revenue from a playback of a video you do not own directly through YouTube.

You could however sign up for Google Adsense and place adverts on the web page that holds each video. This way every time a video/page is loaded if the advert is viewed/clicked you would generate revenue. Read more [here](http://www.google.com/adsense/start/).

I highly advise reading the terms and conditions of Google Adsense carefully however as the rules are very strict on this sort of thing.

Comment: Yea I read through some of the documentation and terms, but found them pretty vague. What I would like to do is play a video advertisement every time somebody clicks play. Video ads can earn as much as 30 cents per click so it is a very attractive revenue stream.

Comment: @Rob Indeed. I can tell you it's certainly possible to do that sort of thing in terms of programming but you just have to watch you don't break these terms and conditions as they'll hit you hard if you do. I'm not sure if YouTube will like companies adding their own adverts to the start/end of a video (but that doesn't mean it can't be done)

Comment: @Rob I second the arguments made by jskidd3. Those ads are meant to be monetized by the creator, not by people syndicating the content. The terms of service do not generally prohibit you from monetizing your website if you embed YouTube videos, but you are not allowed to modify the ads per playback if you are not a video content creator.