# Am I allowed to use google API with video clips?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

In my app users should buy(unlock) video before watching it. Is that allowed by google IAP, can i use google IAP for that purpose?

I do not use adsense, youtube, etc... I just want to know can google android IAP can be used in such condition. Will i break some rules and my app get banned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Money On YouTube Video API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312071/making-money-on-youtube-video-api)

Comment: Not even close to duplicate, that guy is talking about website. I'm talking about android app.

Comment: The duplicate is about the way you may earn money by letting users pay for videos. It's all about owning the right of the video.

Comment: Ok, my client asked me this and i wasn't sure what to answer. They are video content owners, and they host videos on their server not youtube, vimeo etc. Thanks for answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the video rights, you can.